# Swift init delegation

Tags: ios, swift

One of the things that is most confusing for me about the swift language coming from a Java/C#/C++ background is constructor delegation.

I have [read about it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html), but I am having trouble with a real-life scenario.

I am making a custom "DateView" to display dates.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DateView: UIView {

    private let _dateLabel = UILabel()

    func initLabel() {
        _dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
        addSubview(_dateLabel)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initLabel()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initLabel()
    }
}
```

What I am trouble with is how to properly initialize my class. The `override init` is required, really, to support `IBDesignable` classes.
The `required init` is required for subclasses of UIView.
Is there a proper way to delegate this common code of initializing the `_dateLabel` while utilizing the bounds of the view to initialize the label?

Also, you can't access `self` (`.bounds.width`, `.bounds.height`...) before you call `super.init`

[image: can't call init before initializing label]

You also can't call `super.init` before initializing the `_dateLabel` property; seems to me like a circular problem.

[image: can't call self before init]

I feel like delegating it to a separate function is not the right way of going about this.

/pun for being a convenience initializer it sure is inconvenient... :)

Comment: Another approach is to configure and add your label in `layoutSubviews`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont initialize the variabe when you declare it and remove the ? from the init.

The error is because by the time you access the dateLabel in the initializer its already created outside of the initializer, so its being accessed/used rather than initialized and then used.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DateView: UIView {

private let _dateLabel = UILabel()

func initLabel() {
    _dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
    addSubview(_dateLabel)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initLabel()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initLabel()
}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the _dateLabel is supposed to be constant. I edited the original post. I was trying different things...

Comment: Changing it to private let _dateLabel: UILabel = UILabel() and removing _dateLabel = UILabel() from initLabel works

Comment: Thanks, yeah, but how do I delegate initialization? Call one initializer from the other? Or is the way I did it with the `initLabel` function, the correct way? I was thinking creating a default initializer `convenience init()` and calling it from the other two or something of the sort would be the correct way to do it...

Comment: I think you have mixed the two around. A convenience initializer is "convinient" because it calls the designated initializer to init the object correctly. What you are doing is setting up your view from two "designated" initializers.

Comment: @H3lium, yes, you're right, but wouldn't calling one designated initializer from the other be the correct way to reuse code in this case rather than having a third function, `initLabel`?

Comment: You would generally just have a setupView() function or something to setup everything. The designated initlalizers are creation points that take arguments. They redirect to the setup code. Calling one from the other would result in empty arguments being passed and imo incorrect routing. (in this scenario)